# Understanding Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, windows-8, phonegap-plugins

I've been looking into PhoneGap for a while, I did some search and got the following results.

1. It is a cross-platform tool.
2. But I have to rewrite a lot of code again if I want to have an app for iOS or Windows 8 that is already written for Android(using phonegap). (I understand if the UI is to be same for all the platforms, then coding is reduced a lot.)
3. I have [access to these API's](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/index.html)
4. From the [PhoneGap Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/index.html) I deduced it allows me to create apps that needs hardware access.
5. Now lets suppose I need to access some core OS API's like telephone
       or sms access, I need to create some [plugins](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)
6. I found some [PhoneGape-Plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins) but these plugins are OS
   specific. So, I have to write plug-ins for each platforms separately.
7. Gone through [the Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065610/struggling-between-native-and-phonegap-simple-app-requirements)

From [this comparison](http://chelramsey.com/phonegap-vs-native-builds-a-12-month-review/) and few other native apps gives better performance and better UX. If my finding are correct,

then why should I choose PhoneGap over native?
Or am I missing something crucial here?

I want to start developing for Windows 8 development and I have to learn C#/XAML also I will be needing to learn JS/HTML/CSS if I choose PhoneGap. (already working on Android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes
2. The only code that you have to rewrite is device-specific code for accessing certain hardware functions that are not currently available, aka, a custom plugin. Cordova has a lot of plugins already, like an SMS plugin (not sure about Telephone but I'd expect it to exist.) You can use a mobile framework like Dojo Mobile or JQuery Mobile that will automatically adjust and change the UI elements to match the native device UI elements. I think using one of these frameworks is basically a requirement of making a hybrid app.
3. Correct, but each API has a slightly different level of support among all platforms.
4. Yes, the point of Cordova is to let you access device functionality through JavaScript. Otherwise, in order to access hardware functionality, you would need to write a native app.
5. Yes, if the plugin does not exist or does not support your platform, you'll have to either create or extend the plugin.
6. The plugin repo is separated by platform, sometimes people write plugins covering multiple platforms (it'd be nice if they always did this but usually people only write plugins for the platform they need.) So yes, you probably would need to write them.

I think that we are at the point where web technologies have evolved and the browsers on the phones are powerful enough where the native performance is not really going to be greater than hybrid performance. Sure there are probably some exceptions, but [I think Fastbook proved HTML5 apps can perform equally well as native.](http://www.sencha.com/blog/the-making-of-fastbook-an-html5-love-story)

You should choose Phonegap/Cordova over native if you want to target multiple mobile OS's without learning Java, C#, and other native technologies. Some other benefits that it provides are a single HTML code base (easy to maintain) and packaging your webapp as native (easy distribution in the app stores.) However, if you have very specific hardware functionality needs that are not supported by Cordova or by the plugins, then you'll end up having to learn those native languages anyway. At that point, and if you are only targeting a single operating system (like Windows Mobile), it may/probably makes sense to just do the entire app in the native language. However, I don't really think anybody should target a single operating system; future proof your app by writing it in HTML5/JavaScript and then use Cordova to publish it to every operating system.