# webapp to android/ios apps? (for dummies)

Tags: php, android, ios, jquery-mobile, web-applications

Here's the situation:

- I know how to program in basic web coding language, including: php/mysql/html/jquery/css3
- I have created a website which is mobile and tablet device friendly, which I am hoping to wrap in some kind of "webview" and submit to Android and Apple Stores...
- I understand that `phonegap` is the most popular solution for this but...
- I don't have any advanced programming skills, so I get lost at any sign of "command lines", SDKs, .gits...
- I also found about easy step-by-step service `appsgeyser.com` but apparently has spamming reports by displaying unwanted ads, popups, etc.

So I guess my question is: Is there any way to convert a Webapp to a native/hybrid Android and iOs App, that a "dummy" would understand? Being either a clear tutorial for `phonegap` (screenshots, and dummy instructions)  or any other solution?

I really appreciate your advice!

Thanks.

Comment: a phonegap app is not a native app FYI. native would be java for android or Xcode for iOS

Comment: Wrong, @tyczj, Those "App's" or better, lets call it "Application's" are native -> exactly they are native *web* based which will converted into nativ Android-, Xcode-, Win- or firefoxOS- Apps!

Comment: @lin still not the same as straight java or similar. it may compile down to native but you are not building it natively. which is why its called a hybrid app

Comment: @Tyczj you are wrong again. It's called "web hybrid app", because there are many platforms to write "hybrid apps"! Phonegap just uses "web technologies" to make it work, thats why we call it "web based hybrid app".

Comment: Thanks @tyczj, as I made clear I am not an advanced user... but I'm sure you understood what I meant. I will correct the text in order to close this debate. Thanks again.

Comment: @James, TYCZJ answer is not detailed.

Comment: @lin, I don't think any of this discussion is relevant to the question... no offense, although I do appreciate your input. I would appreciate the discussion would return to the solution in hand.

Comment: @Lin you are still not writing it in native language so its not a native app. if you are using "web technologies" (aka intermediatary code)  and not writing straight native code, its not a native app

Comment: @James, he told ya ... "a phonegap app is not a native app FYI" -> whats is totally wrong. I explained it already. Before compiling your phonegap project into native Android, Xcode, etc. its for sure an "native web application"! Get along with the correct meaning of "native".

Comment: Thanks for your input, still awaiting possible solutions...

Comment: http://cordova.apache.org/#about

Comment: @lin I guess everyone on the internet is wrong with what is considered a native app then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065610/struggling-between-native-and-phonegap-simple-app-requirements. even phonegap states that you can use it without having to deal with `native SDK's`

Comment: @TYCZJ, wrong again. You will be able to run your "www"-phoneGap folder in Web -> ANY TIME! Why you think is ripple-emulator working so? Your phonegap project is a "native web based application" before your compile it. Even if you wish, its not ;) The link you posted is about "hybrid"-Apps. We talking about "web based hybrid apps" !

Comment: Checkout http://trigger.io It's pretty straight forward and fairly easy.

Comment: @TYCZJ, the link you posted is interesting. It tells you the same, what I did. Pro's row: "1 language can be used on every available platform." => which means you writing your App on "1 native platform". In phoneGap, its web based (HTML, CSS, JS, JSON, Ressources, sqlLite, and so on), in xamarin you write nativ C#.. and so on.